# Windows batch: find command and errorlevel

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, nssm

I'm trying to use the find command and errorlevel to evaluate the result of a command

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
...
nssm status MyService | find "SERVICE_STOPPED"
if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
   echo MyService is not running
)
```

Since I know the command "nssm status MyService" returns "SERVICE_STOPPED" I would expect find to set the errorlevel to 0.
Instead it's set to 1.
Why?

Comment: Have you tried `nssm status MyService | more | find "SERVICE_STOPPED"`? I think `more` has some conversion capabilities...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A deleted answer showed the encoding of `nssm` output (I don't have it, so I can't verify). Every letter is encoded with two bytes (the second one being `0x00`). So this (admittedly ugly) workaround should work:

```
nssm status MyService | findstr "S.E.R.V.I.C.E._.S.T.O.P.P.E.D"
if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
    echo MyService is not running
)
```